# changing app permissions on twitter causes auth dialog not to redirect to callback url

Tags: authentication, redirect, twitter, callback, twitter-oauth

I'm having trouble with authentication of my app through twitter when I change the default app permissions on twitter.

Previously, I've had the app permissions be read-only.  I went into the app on dev.twitter.com  and  changed my default permissions to read/write.  If a user had previously authorized the app and had their permissions at read only and then tries to login to the app, it shows them the auth dialog (which makes sense since its now requesting read/write) but the problem is that when you click "Sign in" it doesn't redirect to the callback url and just submits to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate  and nothing happens.

If i revoke the app and then login, everything works fine, also new users that previously didnt have the read-only authorization for htis app also get redirected fine.  Its only for users that currently have the app authorized but with a different level of permissions.

I've tried both by changing the default app permissions on twitter as well as modifying the the x_auth_access_type paramter to the request_token call and they behave the same way.

any idea whats going wrong here?

Comment: omg this is the exact same scenario I just ran into.

Comment: maybe the token changed?